# Visual Studio memory window byte order

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I'm new in Visual Studio, lately I am struggling to debug code because it seems the memory window show bytes in the opposite order of how I need to paste them in the same window to check the content. Example: at address A1000000 is stored an object address AABB0011 whose lower byte is AA. I need to copy and paste and reverse the bytes before paste the address in the same memory window. Is there any way to change the order how memory window display the bytes? I cannot find it in VS2019.

Thank You

Comment: x86 CPUs are little endian: [https://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-15/ass15_3.html](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-15/ass15_3.html)

Comment: You can change how data is displayed.  Byte, word, dword, etc.  It's a setting on the view pane, possibly on the right click menu.  Sounds like you're displaying bytes and need them grouped into larger numbers.

Comment: Changing the mode from bytes to 4-byte integer did the work. They are automatically displayed little endian and I can copy&paste from memory window to its address textbox.